# Node.js endpoint to search inside JSON file not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Search function**

```js
var myFileArray = [
    array1.items,
    desportoNews.items,
    array2.items,
    array3.items,
    array4.items
][0]

function search(searched) {
    myFileArray.forEach(function() {
        var results = { items: [] }
        if (myFileArray.includes(searched)) {
            results.items.push(myFileArray.title)
        }
    })
}
```

**/search Endpoint**

```js
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    searched = 'searchword'
    search(searched)
})
```

**JSON File**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "search on this bla bla "
    }
    {
      "title": "search on this ble ble "
    }
    {
      "title": "diferrent search "
    }
  ]
}
```

This is not returning what it was supposed to. The endpoint doesn't load. I want to output the results array after he pushed all titles with searched string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the you have two main issues. One is that your endpoint isn't setting up the response object. You should add:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
  searched="searchword";
  res.json(search(searched));
});
```

That will respond with the json representation of your search.

Additionally the search algorithm is updating `results` which is scoped to just the forEach block and is not returning or updating another variable in that closure. You need to update your search function to actually return the results of the search first and then your endpoint should function as expected. I'm a little confused as to your items structure, but something like this should work:

```
function search(collection, searchKeyword) {
    return collection.filter(function(item) { 
      return item.title.includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()); 
    });
}
```

and you can call the search method like so to get your results:

```
var searchResults = search(myFileArray, 'search');
```

[runnable jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qohanucibi/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: But that doesnt give me the titles that were searched ... I need to have an answer with the titles that were searched

Comment: I want to insert titles searched in another array so i can  show the titles that were searched

Comment: - So your myFileArray initialization is only being set to array1.items because of the [0] indexing. 
- Your search algorithm isn't using the forEach properly because you don't have a value holding the current item. 
- You're storing information into the results variable but never returning it.
- myFileArray.includes is searching the objects and not the titles.

There are some major logic issues and that's the main reason you're not getting a response. I'll update the answer but also check out the jsbin here for the functioning answer: https://jsbin.com/qohanucibi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thank you men!! Please update your asnwer with this code so i can give you a thumbs up!!

Comment: But that only gives one output, imagine that i want multiple outputs that have the same keyword... One more thing if i search 'word' or 'WORD' and i have a 'word' in my json file with will no find that 'word' when its with caps

Comment: Right now because of the [0] indexing, you're only searching array1.items. You would have to wrap the search method call in another foreach block and that would search all `items` collections you have. If you could update your question with example input and output, I might be able to understand your problem better.

Comment: It only returns one item and i need to return multiples items that have the same keyword. I updated the json file

Comment: Ok, so you want the actual item that has a title that matches the keyword and not the title itself. In that case, just remove the map and it'll work. I've added your new use cases into the jsbin here that shows it returning all the items that have the keyword in the title: https://jsbin.com/gehenatila/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: searchResults.forEach(function(result){
  console.log(searchResults);
}); In this code what is this parameter result?

Comment: the forEach method takes in a function to call on each item in the collection that accepts one argument. result holds the contents of that current iteration of the loop. If the code is working as expected, can you please upvote and mark as the answer? ----- MDN is a very useful guide for these types of questions as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Your function its okay but like my title have uppercase and lowercase like imagine 'Example' and 'example' and with the function that you did that will not search.

Comment: ok then just add this modification. You need to match on the same casing then: item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase());

Comment: Greg Van Gorp in your example how do i search on all myFileArray files? I noticed that problem now i was think that was because of [0] index but then its says included not defined